# Comparing two arrays and updating a value based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular, I have two arrays,

```js
internal = [
 {"name": 123, "doName": cityA, "dataType": string},
 {"name": 345, "doName": cityB, "dataType": string},
 {"name": 567, "doName": cityC, "dataType": string},
 {"name": 789, "doName": cityD, "dataType": string},
]
```

and

```js
plans = [
 {"user": personA, "idData": 111, "datatype": string},
 {"user": personB, "idData": 222, "datatype": string},
 {"user": personC, "idData": 333, "datatype": string},
 {"user": personD, "idData": 123, "datatype": string}
]
```

The goal is that inside of a cell renderer, id.cell-renderer.ts, to return the value of either 1) the doName of the user from plans array if the "name" from the internal array and "idData" from the plans array match, and if not, just return the "idData" from the plans array. For example, the table would show

[image]

All the data comes from the plans array except for the last row idData which gets replaced by the doName from internal array because the name of 123 from the internal matched the 123 of the idData from the plans array.

The next step would be to compare the two arrays `plans` and `internal` on the key values of 'idData' and 'name' and where the two values are the same, replace 'idData' from the plans array with the value of the 'doName' from the internal array but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution here is to create a map first, and then access it by id. This reduces complexity from O(n) to O(1) while searching by id.

```js
// create map of internal items by their id
// can be memoized, for example in react useMemo can be used
const internalById = internal.reduce((r, x) => {
  r[x.name] = x
  return r
}, {})

const renderCell = (plan) => {
  // try to get internal doName by id, use plan.idData if not found
  const name = internalById[plan.idData]?.doName ?? plan.idData

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key concept will be you need to iterate each item in the `plans` array and override the `idData` value if the associated `external` object does exist.

```
plans.map((x: any) => ({
  ...x,
  idData:
    internal.find((y: any) => y.name == x.idData)?.doName ?? x.idData,
}));
```

---

Unsure what is your `subs.sink` type:

If `subs.sink` is an array, you shouldn't assign the Subscription to it

```
combineLatest([this.plans$, this.internal$]).subscribe(
  ([plans, internal]: any) => {
    if (!plans || !internal) return;
    this.subs.sink = plans.map((x: any) => ({
      ...x,
      idData:
        internal.find((y: any) => y.name == x.idData)?.doName ?? x.idData,
    }));
  }
);
```

If `subs.sink` is an `Observable`:

```
this.subs.sink = combineLatest([this.plans$, this.internal$]).pipe(
  map(([plans, internal]) => {
    //if (!plans || !internal) return;

    return plans.map((x: any) => ({
      ...x,
      idData:
        internal.find((y: any) => y.name == x.idData)?.doName ?? x.idData,
    }));
  })
);
```

And you should subscribe to the `Observable` via `async` pipe:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr *ngFor="let sink of (subs.sink | async)">
    <td>{{ sink.idData }}</td>
    <td>{{ sink.user }}</td>
    <td>{{ sink.datatype }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-v9wp9g?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: `sub.sink` is an array, you should use the Approach 1 that I provide for `sub.sink` is an array.